# Как обновить юзера в БД?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

У меня на сайте есть юзеры, я добавил возможность обноволять их некоторые поля: имя и фотографию, но с обновлением хотя бы имени возникают огромные проблемы, при выполнении _db.SaveChanges(); вылетает ошибка

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 'Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.'

Вот код

```c
public void SaveUser(ApplicationUser user) {
  if (user.Id ==
    default)
    _db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Added;
  else
    _db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
  _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Я бы вообще написал вот так

```c
_db.Users.Add(user);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Но это не работает, а тот вариант с _db.Entry(user) работает для других сущностей на сайте, а для юзеров почему-то не работает, подскажите как это можно пофиксить, если кто знает в чём здесь проблема.!

Comment: я вот [так](https://github.com/tym32167/battleyemanager/blob/master/src/BattlEyeManager.Spa/Api/Admin/UserController.cs#L131) добавлял, [так](https://github.com/tym32167/battleyemanager/blob/master/src/BattlEyeManager.Spa/Api/Admin/UserController.cs#L79) обновлял

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, единственное чего не понял, эту запись HttpPost(int id) ну то есть зачем мы туда передаем параметр и как выглядит эта ссылка на View, то есть что нужно использовать чтобы в HttpPost(int id) было id. А зачем в целом нам нужно id конечно понятно

Comment: `[HttpPost("{id}")]` id там не обязательный, мне просто хотелось для post запросов использовать тот же url, что для get запросов.

Comment: Ссылка, что для get или post будет выглядеть как mysite.com/api/user/1234